# How to unschedule all jobs using Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Today, I iterate

```
public void unschedule(final ScheduledEvent event) throws SchedulerException {
     ...
    scheduler.deleteJob(event.getName(), "my group");
     ...
}
```

If what i want is to unschedule all jobs, can this be done better (faster)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Scheduler#clear()` will delete EVERYTHING, including triggers and calendars

If that's too severe, then I think your iterator is the only alternative

Comment: `        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>` does not have this method, it seems

Comment: I was going off of the 2.1 javadoc

Comment: with 1.8 you can call `shutdown(false)` and then reallocate the scheduler with `new`, however this may be less efficient than your iterator